# inconsistent java and sql object types

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

Есть типы в БД:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_type IS OBJECT (
id VARCHAR2(20),
name VARCHAR2(40),
phone NUMBER
);
```

Пытаюсь создать обьекты с использованием этих типов:

```
....
Object[] myArray = new Object[3];
Object[] struct = new Object[values.size()];

int arrayIndex = 0;
for (User user : values) {
    myArray[0] = user.id().toString();
    myArray[1] = user.getName().toString();
    myArray[2] = user.getPhone();

    struct[arrayIndex++] = con.createStruct("my_type",myArray);
}
```

На строке с созданием структуры con.createStruct выпадает ошибка:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Inconsistent java and sql object types, for classes implementing ORAData or OracleData, respective factory classes ORADataFactory and OracleDataFactory should be registered in typeMap.
```

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Почему вы, как в сообщении об ошибке говорится, не исрользуете OraData? И причём здесь массив?  На БД вы не создали массива.

Comment: Вы что хотите делать ? сохранить данные пользователя в БД? Что в БД хотите вызвать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это помогло мне.

```
for (User user : values) {
    struct[arrayIndex++] = con.createStruct(
        "my_type",
        new Object[]{
            user.id().toString();
            user.getName().toString();
            user.getPhone();
        });
}
```

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, а насчёт довольно схожей проблемы у вас нет идеи?
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/782772/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B-%D0%B2-sql-%D0%B8-java